# Access Azure DevOps repo connectivity on Azure VM without Internet

Tags: azure, azure-devops

We have code repositories on Azure Devops example url :https://dev.azure.com/myorg/myproject

We also have Azure VM created. Our Azure VM is windows 10. When we create a new VM on azure, Internet is enabled by default.

The VM will be shared with development team member. To secure code, developer should NOT be able to use personal email boxes and any other drives like dropbox, onedrive etc. So what i feel i need is we need is Internet disabled but only access to Azure DevOps repo. Is this possible? How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Network Security Group` resource in Azure. Set rules to allow traffic only to specified services (in your example Azure DevOps) and deny rest of the connections.

https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/azure/virtual-network/security-overview